A union of unions needn't be a union? (Sans AC)
For any collection $\mathscr C$ of sets, write $\Upsilon(\mathscr C)$ for the collection of arbitrary unions in $\mathscr C$. Now, I ask the innocent question of idempotency of $\Upsilon$:

Is $\Upsilon(\Upsilon(\mathscr C)) = \Upsilon(\mathscr C)$?

"$\supseteq$" is clearly true. So, let's analyze the other direction: Let $\mathscr A\subseteq \Upsilon(\mathscr C)$. For each $A\in\mathscr A$, choose a $\mathcal C_A\subseteq\mathscr C$ such that $A = \bigcup\mathcal C_A$. Then $\bigcup\mathscr A = \bigcup_{A\in\mathscr A} \bigl(\bigcup \mathcal C_A\bigr) = \bigcup\bigl(\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr A} \mathcal C_A\bigr)\in \Upsilon(\mathscr C)$.
This usage of the full power of AC raises the following questions:

Is a "better" proof known that uses milder versions of choice?
Does the idempotence of $\Upsilon$ (for all $\mathscr C$'s) imply any form choice?


I don't see why this is idempotent with or without the Axiom of Choice. ${{\varnothing} }$.

@AsafKaragila I thought that it was clear that idempotence of $\Upsilon$ meant its idempotence action on all $\mathscr C$'s. Nevertheless, I have edited it in.

Can't we just choose $\mathcal C_A $ to be the set of all $B \subseteq A$?

I think it might be worth explicitly defining in your question what you mean by "collection of arbitrary unions" $\Upsilon(\mathscr C)$. If I am reading this right, you are talking about the collection of sets of the form $\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr D}A$, where $\mathscr D\subseteq\mathscr C$.

@Joe Yes, you are correct.

@ZoeAllen That solves everything! (If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.)

I don't think you understood my comment.

@AsafKaragila If $\mathscr{C}={x}$ is any singleton, then $\Upsilon(\mathscr C)={\varnothing, x}=\Upsilon(\Upsilon(\mathscr C))$.

@AlexKruckman: Yes, I got that, since the $\Upsilon$ operation is about unions from subsets of $\scr C$. I think this is a clarity on the definition and use of terminology rather than a mathematical issue. This was pointed out by Joe in a previous comment, but was never really addressed in an edit.

In any case, I have closed the question as a duplicate, since essentially the same answer applies here (as remarked by Zoe Allen).
